# Implicit Integration Help

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

$\frac{dy}{dx}+2ty=e^{-t^2}$, solve for $y$.

**attempt**

$e^{\int2t}=e^{t^2}$

$e^{t^2}\frac{dy}{dx}+2te^{t^2}y=e^{t^2}e^{-t^2}$

$\int \frac{d}{dx}(e^{t^2}y)=\int 1$

$e^{t^2}y=x+c \implies y=\frac{x}{e^{t^2}}+\frac{c}{e^{t^2}}$

Comment: $t$ & $x$ seem to be muddled ? ... $ \frac{d}{dx}e^{t^2}=2te^{t^2}\frac{dt}{dx}$ ... ?

Comment: As  Donald Splutterwit commented, if $x$ stands for $t$ (or vice-cersa), your answer is correct.